# Should the question looking for ArXiv alternatives for math and physics be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicates

[What are pre-print repositories for math and physics alternative to ArXiv?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/37976/14341)

As the question is focus on math and physics solely, it isn't a dupe of the other question. Should it be reopened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your assessment, and a few others also seem to agree as well (based on "reopen" vote count). It's been reopened.

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't attract much attention after my edit to get reopened sooner.